# How do I specify a field that can be validated but not stored in Waterline?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm looking at the example in the Waterline docs [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#custom-validations).

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  types: {
    // snip
    password: function(password) {
      return password === this.passwordConfirmation;
    });
  },

  attributes: {
    // snip
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      password: true
    },

    passwordConfirmation: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way to tell Waterline that `passwordConfirmation` is not part of the schema so that it is not created if migrate is set to `alter` or `drop`, or if using a schemaless DB engine?

The actual use case I want is for a clear text `password` field to validated from the request, but use `beforeCreate` to populate a `hash` field that is actually stored (but not allowing the `password` property to be stored in the process).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waterline doesn't support transient fields that are validated but not persisted.  You can add the `schema: true` property to your model which will have it filter out any attributes that aren't explicitly declared, but still make them available in lifecycle callbacks.  You'd have to do the validation for those attributes manually (in `beforeCreate()` or `beforeValidate()` for example), and you'd lose the ability to add arbitrary fields to schemaless dbs, but it's not necessarily a bad solution.

For your case though, I don't see why it's exactly necessary.  Why not just hash the password in `beforeCreate` and save it back to `password`?

```
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {

   values.password = hash(values.password);
   return cb();

}
```

Comment: The problem I'm wrestling with is trying to validate a clear text password when it comes in, but ignore those validations after the hash is created. So it makes it awkward to recycle the password field as you suggest.